# grails: what's the equivalent of php's $_POST and $_GET

Tags: grails

I'm dealing with an example PHP scrip that uses `$_POST` and `$_GET`.  Can you tell me, what's the grail's equivalent of php's `$_POST` and `$_GET`?

Comment: You want to make `POST` and `GET` calls from a grails web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails store the info sent in the request in a `Map` called `params`.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html

The type of this map is GrailsParameterMap, you can check [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsParameterMap.html) the methods available.